# iphone 6+ real device on landscape view is not working

Tags: ios, iphone-6-plus

An user reported that the iOS app on an iPhone 6+, the landscape view is not working.

I don't have a real iPhone 6+ to test it, but on the simulator it works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe user has locked the screen orientation?

Comment: Users are generally the issue. However, if you don't mind sharing the mane of the app, I'll test it for you.

Comment: it's weird, because he's sending me a screenshot of the apps that are running on background and I can see that the other apps are in landscape mode, except my app.

Comment: and MANY users are reporting this

Comment: OK, I THINK I could reproduce it, I have to launch the app, when the device is on landscape mode first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using some #define code asking if the device was iPhone6+, and the code wasn't working as expected. So I changed the code to be like this:

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER    ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE &&  IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```